# xlwt cannot parse formula xlwt.Formula("SUM(R[-110]C:R[-1]C)")

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I am trying to add the above mentioned formula to my script and get a parsing error, if I remove the xlwt.formula bit and replace with an = then excel doesn't read the it as a formula and just prints the string.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: never worked with python so i am assuming that you have to use the approach that you are using. Try this `xlwt.Formula(“=SUM(R[-110]C:R[-1]C)”)` In VbA, we usually do it in a Cell(s)... Like this `Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(R[-110]C:R[-1]C)"`

Comment: I have already tried it produces the same error

Comment: What is `xlwt`? Is that a range object?

Comment: @SiddharthRout it's a python module for writing xls files.

Comment: @manish449 take a look: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-excel/iefc5Ldi4TY

Comment: @alecxe thanks for the link but there doesn't seem to a working fix for this so am I right in thinking that xlwt cannot use rc-cell references

Comment: @manish449 yeah, I'm starting to think so too.

Answer (score 9):

This is a great document on xlwt formulas.

https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/examples/formulas.py

Have you tried:

```
w = Workbook()
ws = w.add_sheet('NewWorksheet')

ws.write(0, 0, Formula("SUM(R[-110]C:R[-1]C)"))
```